# How to return to the same view of UITableView after returning from the detail view controller in XCode?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiwebview, xcode4.3, segue

I have written a UITableView code in XCode. Once one of the cells is pressed by user, a new UIWebView is opened via segue. When the user hits the back button to return to the UITableView, I would like the view to be the same part of the UITableView before selecting a cell by user.

To restate my question, while the back button in detailViewController is hit, I would like the same region of the table cells to be shown. Kind of having a memory of where the user were in the table.

May I know how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navid,

This should be the default behavior if your UITableViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController.

If your UITableViewController is not already embedded in a UINavigationController, you can most easily do this in your storyboard by selecting the UITableViewController, then choosing Editor/"Embed in Navigation Controller".

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMangold for your answer. The UITableViewController is already embedded in the UINavigationController, I guess. Because, I can see the navigation bar created by the navigation controller at the top of the table's view. Just to restate my question, while the back button in detailViewController is hit, I would like the same region of the table cells to be shown. Kind of having a memory of where the user were in the table.

Comment: As Michael says, this is the default behaviour. Are you doing anything in viewWillAppear on the table view controller, like reloading the data?

Comment: @jrturton: Yes, you are right. I was doing some extra work in the viewWillAppear, including reloadData. By removing some non-necessary settings, the problem has been fixed.